# How to use BIG5 to pass Chinese characters to BE in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding

The encoding of my database is big5. I tried to modify the transmission encoding to big5 when sending, but I still receive garbled codes. Am I missing something?

I tried to change the Chinese field encoding to big5

```
    NSStringEncoding big5 = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingBig5_HKSCS_1999);

    [paramsArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[self.postParams.orderDesc dataUsingEncoding:big5 allowLossyConversion:false] forKey:@"orderDesc "]];
```

I tried to modify the encoding to big5 when transmitting

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.requestURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:TIMEOUT_SECONDS];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = [postBodyString dataUsingEncoding:kCFStringEncodingBig5_HKSCS_1999];
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=big5" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: does 'self.postParams.orderDesc'  has Simplified Chinese character?

Comment: No, it's all in traditional Chinese

Comment: from your posted code ,you encode twice? or I misunderstand your code?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't mark it clearly. This is the two ways I did it separately, but both will get garbled characters.